# How to call an overloaded constructor within a constructor of the same class in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have two very related problems; first, to call a overloaded constructor within a same class and second, to reinitialize the calling object with load_from_file() function. Here is an example:

```
class FooA: FooB
{
  FooA();
  FooA(myDataType distribution):FooB(distribution)
  FooA(myClasstype objectA):FooA(objectA.get_distribution){} // suppose objectA has a method get_distribution(). 
..
...

}
```

It gives an error:

> illegal member initialization

Second problem:

```
class FooA: FooB
{
  FooA();
  FooA(myDataType distribution):FooB(distribution)

void load_from_file(string file_name){
         // i have another library function to load from file
         JointDistribution jd = load_from_file(file_name);

        // now i want to re-configure the current object
        *this = FooA(jd);
}
```

> FooA* fa = new FooA();
>
> fa.load_from_file("file_name");

There are different file formats, so it is difficult to put them as a constructor.

Comment: Constructor forwarding is a C++11 feature.  What is your compiler, and what version is it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using Visual C++ 2010.

Answer (score 1):

First problem - if `objectA.get_distribution` is a method, you should have a method call there: `:FooB(objectA.get_distribution())`

Comment: Sorry, it is `:FooA(objectA.get_distribution())` not FooB (i corrected). i want to call an other constructor of the same class.

Comment: @user986789 You need compiler that accepts C++11 then, as one of the other commenters said. It does not work in older standards.

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
    class FooA: FooB
    {
      FooA();
      FooA(myDataType distribution):FooB(distribution)

       void load_from_file(string file_name){
       }
    };
```

function load_from_file is private so you can't call it like you have written:

```
FooA* fa = new FooA();
fa.load_from_file("file_name");
```

constructors are private also... (though sometimes we want them to be private, but I assume here it is not the case xD]

you can call constructor from constructor:

```
class CComplex{
public:
    CComplex(int real1,int image1)
    {
        real=real1;
        image=image1;
        const char& x='x';
        CComplex(1,2,3);
    }
    CComplex():real(0),image(0){}
    CComplex(const CComplex &c)
    {
        real=c.real;
        image=c.image;
    }
    CComplex(int i1, int i2, int i3){cout<<"\n123!";}
public:


    int real,image;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, there is no constructor delegation prior to c++11, while the syntax you have used is correct for c++11. Just make sure you've enabled c++11 compilation and it should work fine. If you can't use C++11 you're going to have to duplicate some code.

I can't understand if/what your second question is (regarding reload).

Comment: Thank you, in second question, i want to re-initialize the object by calling its constructor.